# Thread param actuality

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

How can one be sure that thread param will still be actual when thread starts?

**situation 1:** `my_thread` was created, but `param` changed immediately after its creation. We would expect `my_thread` having `param_ptr` that points to `56` but now it does to `89`.

```
DWORD WINAPI my_thread(LPVOID param_ptr);

int param = 56;
CreateThread(NULL, NULL, my_thread, &param, NULL, NULL);
param = 89;
```

**situation 2:** `my_thread` was created, but the `param` does not exist anymore since `create_my_thread` has closed already.

```
DWORD WINAPI my_thread(LPVOID param_ptr);

void create_my_thread(int param)
{
  CreateThread(NULL, NULL, my_thread, &param, NULL, NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass variables via the heap and delete in the thread.  Smart pointers can help in case the API allows them, otherwise just make the habit of allows deleting parameters in the thread function.

```
DWORD WINAPI my_thread(LPVOID param_ptr);

int* param = new(56);
CreateThread(NULL, NULL, my_thread, param, NULL, NULL);
int newParam = 89;
```

Comment: I'm not a fan of manual memory management (new/delete), but there are some cases where it has it use.

Comment: BTW: you could make an exception and pass ints by casting it to LPVOID, but I'm not in favor because it's still an exception, and there could be portability issues and then the rule of always deleting params in the thread function is weaker.

Answer (score 2):

Two points:

1. Don't pass a pointer to a temporary variable.
2. If you want to prevent change to an initial value, start the thread as suspended, then call [`ResumeThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685086%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) afterwards.

Note that, although the parameter you can pass to a thread function is declared as a `VOID` pointer, it doesn't actually have to be a pointer. So if you just want to pass some number (as in your example), you can just cast it:

```
CreateThread(NULL, NULL, my_thread, (LPVOID)56, NULL, NULL);
```

Then in the thread function, do the reverse:

```
DWORD WINAPI my_thread(LPVOID param_ptr)
{
    DWORD dwNumber = (DWORD)param_ptr;

    // dwNumber is now equal to 56
}
```

For pausing and resuming, refer to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for the `CreateThread options and use`CREATE_SUSPENDED`, for example:

```
// create thread but don't start it
HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(NULL, NULL, my_thread, &param, 
                                  CREATE_SUSPENDED, NULL);

// ... make any changes to `param` thst you need your thread to be aware of ...

// start the thread
ResumeThread(hThread);
```

Comment: @user2543574 Well, if you want to pass something to the thread, it has to exist for the duration that the thread needs it. It can be global, or it can be local if you wait for the thread to complete within a function. It can also be a class member variable. See updated answer for another alternative.

Comment: Doesn't it kills multithreading since system won't respond until thread finishes?

Comment: @user2543574 If you mean spawning threads within a function, it can be common to parallelise some processing within a function by spawning say, 4 threads, to process data in parallel, then wait for all four to finish before exiting the function. This can be faster than doing all of the work serially in that function.